# Libcurl - curl_multi_wakeup

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

Reading the function description curl_multi_wakeup: [enter link description here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_wakeup.html)

> Calling this function only guarantees to wake up the current (or the
> next if there is no current) curl_multi_poll call, **which means** it is
> possible that **multiple calls** to this function will wake up **the same**
> **waiting** operation.

I am confused by the phrase - "the same waiting operation". How's that?

That is, suppose I have a function curl_multi_poll() in event standby mode in thread "A".

Now, for example, I call the curl_multi_wakeup() function twice from thread "B" and thread "C".

And what happens judging by this phrase:

> ...function will wake up the same waiting operation.

It turns out that the function curl_multi_poll - wakes up only once ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, so I won't make an answer, but imagine calling `curl_multi_wakeup` 1000 times in a loop before thread A has a chance to wake up even once. I think the documentation is saying that those 1000 calls will only wake up the single `curl_multi_poll` call, rather than the next 1000 calls.

Comment: Read this link: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/12/09/this-is-your-wake-up-curl/.   You SHOULDN'T be calling it 1000s times in multiple threads.  The point is that you'll ONLY invoke curl_multi_wakeup() in an EXCEPTIONAL condition.

Comment: @FoggyDay, it seems that you don't understand why curl_multi_wakeup is needed - I must and will call it 1000 times from different threads - that's what curl_multi_wakeup was created for.

Comment: No, YOU don't understand that it looks like you've got a seriously flawed design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_multi_wakeup` is meant to be used with a pool of threads waiting on `curl_multi_poll`.

What the document says is that if you call `curl_multi_wakeup` repeatedly, it will possibly wake up only a single thread, not necessarily one thread for each call to curl_multi_wakeup.

Comment: the documentation does not say anything at all about the awakening of threads, so it says about the awakening of the curl_multi_poll function().

Comment: It's implicit. How could you possibly wait on curl_multi_poll multiple times?

Comment: I have 10 threads and an infinite loop of curl_easy_perform/curl_multi_poll is running in each thread.

Comment: Well that applies directly to your case then. Be prepared to consume multiple events on that single callback. Actually there is really nothing you need to do if you don't assume that one curl_multi_wakeup will produce one curl_multi_poll callback.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand. What does it mean - " multiple events on that single callback.".   I need to wake up curl_multi_poll - in order to perform a function or curl_multi_remove_handle or curl_multi_add_handle or maybe some other and that's it.

Comment: curl_multi_poll returns the number of fds that need attention as the last argument.

Comment: curl_multi_poll returns the number of fds that need attention as the last argument - ONLY if he returned by himself, and not after the call - curl_multi_wakeup. Number of fds - It has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Imagine I have 10 threads and 10 infinite loops, now imagine that all requests are completed and the curl_multi_poll function is WAITING. Now the question is: how do I add a new CUrl_easy handle to multi_handle if curl_multi_poll - blocked the thread? The only solution is to call the curl_multi_wakeup function so that it wakes up the curl_multi_poll function and unlocks the loop. But there is a problem that two calls to curl_multi_wakeup - according to the documentation - can only wake up curl_multi_poll once.

Answer (score 0):

curl_multi_poll() is a relatively new call, designed to simplify "interrupting" threads waiting on curl_multi_poll().  Here's a good explanation:

> https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2019/12/09/this-is-your-wake-up-curl/
>
> [curl_multi_poll()](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_poll.html)
> [is a] function which asks libcurl to wait for activity on any of the
> involved transfers – or sleep and don’t return for the next N
> milliseconds.
>
> Calling this waiting function (or using the older curl_multi_wait() or
> even doing a select() or poll() call “manually”) is crucial for a
> well-behaving program. It is important to let the code go to sleep
> like this when there’s nothing to do and have the system wake up it up
> again when it needs to do work. Failing to do this correctly, risk
> having libcurl instead busy-loop somewhere and that can make your
> application use 100% CPU during periods. That’s terribly unnecessary
> and bad for multiple reasons.
>
> When ... something happens and the application for example needs to
> shut down immediately, users have been asking for a way to do a wake
> up call.
>
> curl_multi_wakeup() explicitly makes a curl_multi_poll() function
> return immediately. It is designed to be possible to use from a
> different thread.